# Can Synaptic install application from a .tar.gz file downloaded from outside the repositories?

Tags: installation, compiling, synaptic, tar

I would like to know if Synaptic package manager can install an application from a .tar.gz file downloaded from a different source than is in the repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

I mean those files need to run `./configure` , `make`, `sudo make install` to install. Does Synaptic perform these operations?

Comment: Yes, when we do them manually, sometimes problems comes. It takes too much time to struggle with it. So can we hand over these tasks to a application ?. Can Synaptic package manager do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those file where we need to run `./configure , make, sudo make install` are archives with source code of the application in it.

Synaptic is a graphical management software for installing debian packages with all it's dependencies. Those debian packages are precomplied and to put it simply they are just archives containing the binaries and configuration files.

Most modern Linux distributions have a similar systems because compiling every single program by yourself can be partly very painful.

To answer your question: No there is no option to give Synaptic a source package to install it from source, you have to do this by hand.

**But**, in most cases you will find an other repository or a PPA or even a .deb package for this piece of software.

Comment: This information was so useful for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to control your source-code-installation through Synaptic Manager or Ubuntu Software Center (to ease the process of uninstall), you can try

```
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
```

which creates a .deb package. This is can be installed using Ubuntu Software Center.